# iisnode seemingly random service unavailable error

Tags: node.js, unhandled-exception, iisnode

I have a nodejs application setup using iisnode to host through iis.

The site runs great except we randomly get 'the service is unavailable' messages with no more information. The only way to resume to normal is to reset iis. We've got error handling and logging and no errors are being thrown. Wev'e even included:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.log('ERROR Caught exception: ' + err);
});
```

Incase there is anything missed but nothing is thrown. Wev'e checked the event viewer on the machine its run on and nothing, checked the logs in the iisnode folder in our app and again nothing.

Is there any modules or anything else we can do to debug this? There is no information whatsoever to start our investigations with. It feels like its a iisnode issue rather then our app as none of our error handling has been triggered nor the global proccess.on() listener.

Thanks

Comment: For anyone who has any similar experiences, im guessing by the tumble-weed passing that this isn't often, but the issue was caused by available resources on the server. We also had a Team City agent installed on the vm which was causing memory usage to hit over 90% when this happened IISnode would fall over. I useful package we installed was NewRelic to monitor our server. Trouble is for Nodejs its used as a module so if node falls over it stops. But it notified us of the memory usage so we didn't have to sit and watch the box.

Comment: This is very interesting. Happened yesterday when we were doing a live auction. I suspected it had something to do with too many socket connections. I checked the resources of the server when the app crashed, and memory + CPU was stable. Maybe it came down when IIS crashed. Going to look into New Relic.